# Retrieve data from JSON Object using JSON Simple library

Tags: java, json, api, simplejson

This is the JSON object printed to screen:

> {"UserName":"myUsername","Address":"myAddress","Password":"myPassword"}

In the following code, what value goes in `data_obj.get()` & `in obj.get()` to retrieve *UserName* value **myUsername** from JSON Object?

```java
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) data_obj.get();
System.out.println(obj.get("UserName"));
```

I tried this

```java
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) data_obj.get(0);

//Get the required data using its key
System.out.println(obj.get("UserName"));
```

but I got null pointer and was expecting the data for *UserName* field equals **myUsername**.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably performing a redundant step.

That's how the data you've shared can be parsed:

```
String jsonStr = """
        {"UserName":"myUsername","Address":"myAddress","Password":"myPassword"}
    """;
        
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("UserName"));
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("Address"));
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("Password"));
```

*Output:*

```
myUsername
myAddress
myPassword
```